# Can Newton's Law of Cooling be viewed as an eigenvalue problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, heat-equation

Newton's Law of Cooling states that the rate of heat loss of a body is directly proportional to the difference in the temperatures between the body and its surroundings. Written as:
$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} \propto u - u_{a}$$
with $u$ being temp of the object and $u_a$ being the surrounding temp.

Then solving this, I believe this can be written as:
$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} = \lambda\left(u - u_{a}\right)$$

Where, (with the boundary conditions under which this law is approx true, and this value is a constant) $\lambda$ is a negative constant loosely representing a heat transfer coefficient that makes this an equation.

*I am curious whether or not this $\lambda$ can be viewed as or solved as an eigenvalue.* My line of reasoning is that the time differential of $u$ might be able to be viewed as a linear transformation? This would make the corresponding eigenfunction $u(t)$, I believe.

Comment: I would say yes. Eigenvalue/Eigenvector problem is not restricted to matrix theory only. If you view the space of functions as a vector space, then the differential operator is a linear transformation. In this case, the exponential function is an eigenfuction. A similar example is the exponential decay in radioactivity.